# Eclipse Luna - Error while installing Hibernate Tool

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

In Eclipse Luna I am trying to install Hibernate Tool for Luna from this [Site](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/). I am getting below multiple errors. Find error details below:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.hibernate.eclipse.libs,4.0.1.Final-v20150324-2307-B95.
Unpacking fails because intermediate file is empty: C:\Users\KAVIAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\work9090771654182401354\p2.optimizers.incoming4124867544172107522.jar
Error closing the output stream for osgi.bundle,org.hibernate.eclipse.libs,4.0.1.Final-v20150324-2307-B95 on repository file:/D:/eclipse/.
Error unzipping C:\Users\KAVIAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_4.0.1.Final-v20150324-2307-B951612824584468310603.jar: Invalid zip file format
```

I can't able to find the solution for this, Please give your idea.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse tried to download files from the website, then unzip it to install.

in your case, it couldn't download files, or downloaded files were corrupted.

Check your internet connection then try again.

Comment: Yes my internet connection is good, I can able to browse the URL

Answer (score 0):

as I understand, it tried to download this link:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/features/org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_4.0.1.Final-v20150324-2307-B951612824584468310603.jar

or

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/features/org.hibernate.eclipse.libs_4.0.1.Final-v20150324-2307-B95.jar

but both of these links are died now.